# If metadata in flv container must be recorded at the beginning of the file?

Tags: video, containers, metadata, rtmp, flv

I'm work with flv  container and i need to know if it's need to write metadata at the beginning of the flv file or i can add metadata in the middle of the file?

Comment: Do you mean arbitrary metadata? Or codec specific metadata (extradata/sequence headers)?

Comment: Arbitrary metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLV stores metadata in script tags. It's JSON like binary structure. Script tags have their own timestamp (relative to 0, and on the same millisecond time line as audio and video). They can be placed anywhere in the stream but must have monotonic time stamps.